# MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid after upgrading from material v4 to v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I recently upgraded from Material V4 to V5 and I'm now getting the following error:

```
MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
```

Within my `App.js` file, I have the following setup:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider, adaptV4Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles';
import { CssBaseline, Hidden } from '@mui/material';


let theme = createTheme(adaptV4Theme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#63ccff',
      main: '#009be5',
      dark: '#006db3'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    h5: {
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: 26,
      letterSpacing: 0.5
    }
  },
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 8
  },
  props: {
    MuiTab: {
      disableRipple: true
    }
  },
  mixins: {
    toolbar: {
      minHeight: 48
    }
  }
}));

theme = {
  ...theme,
  overrides: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      paper: {
        backgroundColor: '#18202c'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

and then have the following return within my App.js:

```
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <NotifyProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />}></Route>
        </Routes>
          <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <nav className={classes.drawer}>
                </nav>
                <div className={classes.app}>
                  <Header
                    onDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
                  />
                  <main className={classes.main}>
                    <Routes>
                      <Route path="/" />
                    </Routes>
                  </main>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </StyledEngineProvider>
    </NotifyProvider>
  );
```

I'm not sure what the issue is and what I am missing but I also noticed that `adaptV4Theme` is depracated.

Any help would be great as the app is not starting at all.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW,

I recently ran into this issue while upgrading from `5.11.7` to `5.12.2` which was odd. It turns out I had accidentally only updated my version of `@mui/material` but forgot to update other `@mui` packages too.

In the end, I updated the following libs to the same level:

```
@mui/icons-material
@mui/material
@mui/styles
@mui/system
```

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same issue. there is a thread here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30092 with some troubleshooting suggestions. none of them worked for me but some others in the thread seem to have resolved the issue by deleting `yarn.lock` and rerunning `yarn install`, see thread for more details. if you do solve it please post here and let me know what fixed it, have been working at this for several days with no luck.

ETA -- I was able to solve this in my app by wrapping the components I was testing in a `<ThemeProvider/>`, as suggested here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/15528#issuecomment-487952731 (I was only getting the error message when testing)